# Android: How to make RadioGroup work correctly in a ListView?

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

I have a ListView, which has a TextView and a RadioGroup with 4 RadioButtons as Children in each row. 
Now i can select a RadioButton in each row. But if i scroll the ListView, my Selection is gone or it does not show correctly. For example, i choose the RadioButton A in the first row, if i scroll through the ListView and then go back to the first row again, either none of the RadioButtons in the RadioGroup is checked or RadioButton C is checked instead of A. 
How can i fix this Problem? I have tried 7 days already, but still i find no solution. Can anybody help me? I'll be very appriciate of that.

Comment: could you best your getView method from the adapter your using?

Comment: hi tian dong i am also havin this same problem please provide me the ideas .how to prevent this selection state overide in other row of list

Comment: Can you please post here your code, i am interested for this. Thnaks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When `getView()` (or `bindView()` if you are using a `CursorAdapter`) is called on your adapter, you need to set the state of the `RadioGroup`. Android recycles rows and is not going to track those `RadioGroup` states for you.

[See here for a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/FancyLists/RateList/) that has a `RatingBar` in a row for the general technique. This is also covered in [this free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one my books.

Comment: Unbelievable, it works! I'm soo....oo happy!
And the free excerpt helps me a lot to understand how ListView of Android works.
Thank you very much. I am really very appreciate of your help