# How to set that only one checkbox is selected at once in a ListView in android

Tags: android, listview

I have created a dynamic listview which contains a CheckBox.what I want is at once only one CheckBox should be selected from List & Other should be deselected.How can I do this 
Plz Help

Comment: there must be a radiobutton or something for that, not checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RadioGroup as previously mentioned is discussed in detail here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#RadioButtons

For more about what you appear to be trying to do, let me point you to [Android: How to make RadioGroup work correctly in a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937581/android-how-to-make-radiogroup-work-correctly-in-a-listview)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [RadioGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html) class.

Comment: How can I use RadioGroup in a ListView