# How to handle radio buttons value on listview

Tags: android, listview, radio-button

I have been working on a project where i need to mark attendance of employees and store it in database..for that i implemented radio buttons in radio group which will determine whether an employee is present absent or on half day leave....to do this i must get those values from list view and on clicking the done button attendance must be marked and stored in database....

My problem is how do i get the values o those radio buttons from my custom list view and handle those data!!??

My code for custom list adapter

```
public class CustomCalendarAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final Bitmap[] imgid;

public CustomCalendarAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Bitmap[] imgid) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item2, itemname);

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;
}

@Nonnull
public View getView( int position, View view,@Nonnull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    final RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.rb3);

    rb2.setChecked(true);
    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(imgid[position]);
    extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);

    return rowView;

} }
```

My code for list view xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rowselector"
    android:padding="5dp" />

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/rowselector"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="#000" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/rg"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb1"
        android:text="P"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb2"
        android:text="A"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/rb3"
        android:text="HD"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RadioGroup>
```

My code for activity with listview in which i want to display list and handle done button

```
public class Attendance extends AppCompatActivity {

CustomCalendarAdapter adapter;
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<>();
ListView lv;

    @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    myinfodbhelper mDbHelper = new myinfodbhelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
            + myinfocontract.myinfoentry.TABLE_NAME,null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String currentfname = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        byte[] bytes = cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex("image"));
        Bitmap bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

        strings.add(currentfname);
        bitmaps.add(bitmap);
    }
    cursor.close();

    String[] itemname = strings.toArray(new String[0]);
    Bitmap[] imageid = bitmaps.toArray(new Bitmap[0]);
    adapter = new CustomCalendarAdapter(this, itemname, imageid);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setEmptyView(tv);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Here I want to handle the radio button check
            //And mark done by the floatingActionButton id in my listview xml file
        }
    });
```

if this question has already been answered plz provide link

i could not find relevant solution to my problem hence iam asking this question... what modification must be done??

Thx in advance...

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**

Create a Bean class of your data with an integer variable `attendance_type`. And pass the list of that data to your adapter.

**Step 2**

Set a click listener on your radio group. and set the `attendance_type`(whatever selected) back on radio check changed to the list and change it in database too.

**Step 3**

Now every time you change the attendance you will have an updated list.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id of the checked radio button id using the following code

```
int checked_btn_id = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

You also need to create a model class to store the value and to manage the scrolling issue [Issue when scrolled down when radio checked items are not seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930858/listviews-checked-items-not-there-after-scrolling)