# Android ListView RadioButtons

Tags: android

I have a Custom List View where each item in the List contains a Radio Button. I want only one Radio Box in the List to be selected. How can do this ? If i place the Radio Group on the layout i inflate, each Radio Button will be added to it own group ?

Kind regards,
Mateen

Comment: try this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937581/android-how-to-make-radiogroup-work-correctly-in-a-listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a custom adapter you can yourself uncheck the previously checked radiobutton when a other list item is selected.

Comment: It would be much usefull if you write how to do this

Answer (score 8):

U can set the adapter like this...

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,android.R.id.text1, names));
```

Refer this link it may helpfull.. http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: No, I want it to Work with a Custom List Adapter. This does not help me.