# Android : Change CheckBox checked value in ListView when getFilter() called

Tags: android, android-listview, android-alertdialog, android-filter, android-filterable

I recently [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30724689/1318946) my Question for `MultiSpinner` values to choose Multiple values from Spinner dialog. I've done successfully with following class.

**MultiSpinnerSearch.java**

```
package com.example.multiplechoicelistwithfilter;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class MultiSpinnerSearch extends Spinner implements OnCancelListener {

    private List<Hello> items;
    //private boolean[] selected;
    private String defaultText;
    private MultiSpinnerListener listener;

    public MultiSpinnerSearch(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MultiSpinnerSearch(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public MultiSpinnerSearch(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // refresh text on spinner

        StringBuffer spinnerBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).isSelected() == true) {
                spinnerBuffer.append(items.get(i).getName());
                spinnerBuffer.append(", ");
            }
        }

        String spinnerText = "";
        spinnerText = spinnerBuffer.toString();
        if (spinnerText.length() > 2)
            spinnerText = spinnerText.substring(0, spinnerText.length() - 2);
        else
            spinnerText = defaultText;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                new String[] { spinnerText });
        setAdapter(adapter);

        listener.onItemsSelected(items);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle(defaultText);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_listview_search, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.alertSearchListView);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.alertSearchEditText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {  
            }
        });

        //builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items.toArray(new CharSequence[items.size()]), selected, this);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                SparseBooleanArray sp = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

                for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++) {
                    items.get(i).setSelected(sp.get(i));
                }               
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.setOnCancelListener(this);
        builder.show();
        return true;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Hello> items, String allText, int position,
            MultiSpinnerListener listener) {

        this.items = items;
        this.defaultText = allText;
        this.listener = listener;

        // all selected by default
        //selected = new boolean[items.size()];
        //for (int i = 0; i < selected.length; i++)
        //  selected[i] = false;    

        if(position != -1)
        {
            items.get(position).setSelected(true);
            listener.onItemsSelected(items);

            onCancel(null);
        }

    }

    public interface MultiSpinnerListener {
        public void onItemsSelected(List<Hello> items);
    } 
}
```

**MyAdapter class:**

```
package com.example.multiplechoicelistwithfilter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

        List<Hello> arrayList;      
        List<Hello> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, List<Hello> arrayList) {
            this.arrayList = arrayList;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            CheckedTextView textView;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice, null);
                holder.textView = (CheckedTextView) convertView;

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.textView.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
            holder.textView.setChecked(arrayList.get(position).isSelected());
            return convertView;
        }

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

                    arrayList = (List<Hello>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                    notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                    List<Hello> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<Hello>();

                    if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<Hello>(arrayList); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                    }

                    /********
                     * 
                     *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
                     *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)  
                     *
                     ********/
                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                        // set the Original result to return  
                        results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                        results.values = mOriginalValues;
                    } else {
                        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                            Log.i("TAG", "" + mOriginalValues.get(i).getName() + " -> " + mOriginalValues.get(i).isSelected());
                            String data = mOriginalValues.get(i).getName();
                            if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                                FilteredArrList.add(mOriginalValues.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        // set the Filtered result to return
                        results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                        results.values = FilteredArrList;
                    }
                    return results;
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }
```

> I am getting output successfully as below, but in first image suppose
>   i am select first two image and then filtering word 'ball' it gives me
>   filtered result with **selected checkbox as before.**

[image]

> You can see that first two items not selected before but it shows
>   selected while filtering.

[image]

I am stuck with this silly problem since last couple of hours. Help me.

Your help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: not sure if this might be any good but I had a similar problem with radio buttons loosing it's state while scrolling. Have a look here, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102820/radiogroup-buttons-loosing-its-state-after-listview-scroll/20238434#20238434

Comment: i am not loosing state but it is not changing checked value when filtering for unchecked items.

Comment: @PratikButani Could not find com.github.pratikbutani:MultiSelectSpinner:08d324c987 . Is this library still available??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created my own lib and uploaded on Git:

May It will help you all:

[MultiSelectSpinner](https://github.com/pratikbutani/MultiSelectSpinner) is allows to Select Multiple Items from Spinner and **SEARCH/ FILTER** Item from Spinner Items.

```
public class MultiSpinnerSearch extends Spinner implements OnCancelListener {

    private List<KeyPairBoolData> items;
    //private boolean[] selected;
    private String defaultText;
    private MultiSpinnerSearchListener listener;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    public MultiSpinnerSearch(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MultiSpinnerSearch(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1) {
        super(arg0, arg1);
    }

    public MultiSpinnerSearch(Context arg0, AttributeSet arg1, int arg2) {
        super(arg0, arg1, arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // refresh text on spinner

        StringBuffer spinnerBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).isSelected() == true) {
                spinnerBuffer.append(items.get(i).getName());
                spinnerBuffer.append(", ");
            }
        }

        String spinnerText = "";
        spinnerText = spinnerBuffer.toString();
        if (spinnerText.length() > 2)
            spinnerText = spinnerText.substring(0, spinnerText.length() - 2);
        else
            spinnerText = defaultText;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                R.layout.textview_for_spinner,
                new String[] { spinnerText });
        setAdapter(adapterSpinner);

        if(adapter != null)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        listener.onItemsSelected(items);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean performClick() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle(defaultText);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_listview_search, null);
        builder.setView(view);

        final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.alertSearchListView);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        listView.setFastScrollEnabled(false);
        adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext(), items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        EditText editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.alertSearchEditText);
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {  
            }
        });

        //builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items.toArray(new CharSequence[items.size()]), selected, this);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

//              items = (ArrayList<KeyPairBoolData>) adapter.arrayList;

                Log.i("TAG", " ITEMS : " + items.size() );
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        builder.setOnCancelListener(this);
        builder.show();
        return true;
    }

    public void setItems(List<KeyPairBoolData> items, String allText, int position,
            MultiSpinnerSearchListener listener) {

        this.items = items;
        this.defaultText = allText;
        this.listener = listener;

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterSpinner = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                R.layout.textview_for_spinner,
                new String[] { defaultText });
        setAdapter(adapterSpinner);

        if(position != -1)
        {
            items.get(position).setSelected(true);
            //listener.onItemsSelected(items);
            onCancel(null);
        }
    }

    public interface MultiSpinnerSearchListener {
        public void onItemsSelected(List<KeyPairBoolData> items);
    }

    //  // Adapter Class            
    public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

        List<KeyPairBoolData> arrayList;      
        List<KeyPairBoolData> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
        LayoutInflater inflater;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, List<KeyPairBoolData> arrayList) {
            this.arrayList = arrayList;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView textView;
            CheckBox checkBox;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;

            if (convertView == null) {

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_listview_search_subview, null);
                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alertTextView);
                holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.alertCheckbox);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            final KeyPairBoolData data = arrayList.get(position);

            holder.textView.setText(data.getName());
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(data.isSelected());

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    ViewHolder temp = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                    temp.checkBox.setChecked(!temp.checkBox.isChecked());

                    int len = arrayList.size();
                    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                    {
                        if (i == position)
                        {
                            data.setSelected(!data.isSelected());
                            Log.i("TAG", "On Click Selected : " + data.getName() + " : " + data.isSelected());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.checkBox.setTag(holder);

            return convertView;
        }

        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale")
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {

                    arrayList = (List<KeyPairBoolData>) results.values; // has the filtered values
                    notifyDataSetChanged();  // notifies the data with new filtered values
                }

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults results = new FilterResults();        // Holds the results of a filtering operation in values
                    List<KeyPairBoolData> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<KeyPairBoolData>();

                    if (mOriginalValues == null) {
                        mOriginalValues = new ArrayList<KeyPairBoolData>(arrayList); // saves the original data in mOriginalValues
                    }

                    /********
                     * 
                     *  If constraint(CharSequence that is received) is null returns the mOriginalValues(Original) values
                     *  else does the Filtering and returns FilteredArrList(Filtered)  
                     *
                     ********/
                    if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                        // set the Original result to return  
                        results.count = mOriginalValues.size();
                        results.values = mOriginalValues;
                    } else {
                        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                        for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalValues.size(); i++) {
                            Log.i("TAG", "Filter : " + mOriginalValues.get(i).getName() + " -> " + mOriginalValues.get(i).isSelected());
                            String data = mOriginalValues.get(i).getName();
                            if (data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())) {
                                FilteredArrList.add(mOriginalValues.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        // set the Filtered result to return
                        results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                        results.values = FilteredArrList;
                    }
                    return results;
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks :) Keep Sharing :)

Comment: I want MultiSpinner or MultiSpinnerSearch to have setText method, when i select values, it shows on the screen which i do not want.

Comment: hi @PratikButani , what's the license for the library?

Comment: ITs free.. you can use. @Sanket

Comment: @PratikButani Is the plugin available for Xamarin android?

Comment: @PratikButani Could not find com.github.pratikbutani:MultiSelectSpinner:08d324c987 .how to solve this

Comment: It is available on github. You can download whole library and add as a module in your project. That will work.

Comment: @KJEjava48 Check with this and do let me know its working? `implementation 'com.github.pratikbutani:MultiSelectSpinner:08d324c98'`