# CheckedTextView in listview changes position after filter search

Tags: android, listview, xamarin.android, multi-select

I want to implement a multiselect list in **android Xamarin**. For which I have used a custom adapter with `checkedTextview`.

**Adapter class:**

```
 public class FilterableMultiselectAdapter : ArrayAdapter, IFilterable, View.IOnClickListener
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        Filter filter;
        Activity context;
        public List<FilterableListViewModel> AllItems;
        public List<FilterableListViewModel> MatchItems;

        public List<string> SelectedItems= new List<string>();
        private CheckedTextView _checkedText;

        public FilterableMultiselectAdapter(Activity context, int txtViewResourceId, List<FilterableListViewModel> items) : base(context, txtViewResourceId, items)
        {
            inflater = context.LayoutInflater;
            filter = new SuggestionsFilter(this);
            AllItems = items;
            MatchItems = items;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return MatchItems.Count;
            }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public FilterableListViewModel GetMatchedItem(int position)
        {
            return MatchItems[position];
        }

        public List<string> SelectedItemsList()
        {
            return SelectedItems;
        }


        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null)
                view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Drawable.filterMultiselectList_view, null);

            _checkedText = view.FindViewById<CheckedTextView>(Resource.Id.chkTV);

            _checkedText.Text = MatchItems[position].displayName;
            _checkedText.SetOnClickListener(this);

            return view;
        }


        public void OnClick(View V)
        { 
            if (((CheckedTextView)V).Checked)
            {
                // set check mark drawable and set checked property to false
               // value = "un-Checked";
                ((CheckedTextView)V).SetCheckMarkDrawable(0);
                ((CheckedTextView)V).Checked = (false);

            }
            else
            {
                // set cheek mark drawable and set checked property to true
                // value = "Checked";
                ((CheckedTextView)V).SetCheckMarkDrawable(Resource.Drawable.ic_check);
                ((CheckedTextView)V).Checked = (true);
                addItemIntoCheckedList(((CheckedTextView)V).Text);
            }
        }

        private void addItemIntoCheckedList(string id)
        {


            SelectedItems.Add(id);

        }

        public override Filter Filter
        {
            get
            {
                return filter;
            }
        }

        public void ResetSearch()
        {
            MatchItems = AllItems;
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        class SuggestionsFilter : Filter
        {
            readonly FilterableMultiselectAdapter _adapter;

            public SuggestionsFilter(FilterableMultiselectAdapter adapter) : base()
            {
                _adapter = adapter;
            }

            protected override Filter.FilterResults PerformFiltering(Java.Lang.ICharSequence constraint)
            {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(constraint.ToString()))
                {
                    var searchFor = constraint.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine("searchFor:" + searchFor);
                    var matchList = new List<FilterableListViewModel>();
                    //var matches = _adapter.AllItems.Where(i => i.title.ToLower().Contains(searchFor.ToLower()) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.subText) ? 1 == 1 : i.subText.ToLower().Contains(searchFor.ToLower()));

                    var matches = _adapter.AllItems.Where(i => i.item.ToLower().Contains(searchFor.ToLower()));// || (i.subItem != null && i.subItem.ToLower().Contains(searchFor.ToLower())));//   !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.subText) ? i.subText.ToLower().Contains(searchFor.ToLower()) : null);


                    foreach (var match in matches)
                    {
                        matchList.Add(match);
                    }

                    _adapter.MatchItems = matchList;
                    Console.WriteLine("resultCount:" + matchList.Count);

                    List<FilterableListViewModel> matchObjects = new List<FilterableListViewModel>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < matchList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        matchObjects.Add(matchList[i]);
                    }

                    results.Count = matchList.Count;
                }
                else
                {
                    _adapter.ResetSearch();
                }
                return results;
            }

            protected override void PublishResults(Java.Lang.ICharSequence constraint, Filter.FilterResults results)
            {
                _adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue here is that suppose I have 4 items in my list and I selected 1st and 2nd item, And then I go and search for something which gives me the remaining list, then the selection of checkbox does not work correctly.

I tried to find out the issue but I cannot get any work around for the issue. I found a similar question on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30731983/1650891), but the solution of it points to and android library.I cannot use android library as I am using Xamarin android.

If anyone has already figured out the issue then please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a Xamarin developer but i could tell that your code is not optimized. For example, you don't need to use member variable `private CheckedTextView _checkedText;`, but instead use method-scope/local variable. You might want to look at ViewHolder pattern to optimize memory usage and performance. To resolve you issue check the `// TODO` comment from the code snippet, first there is logic error here:

```
public void OnClick(View V)
{ 
    if (((CheckedTextView)V).Checked)
    {
        // set check mark drawable and set checked property to false
       // value = "un-Checked";
        ((CheckedTextView)V).SetCheckMarkDrawable(0);
        ((CheckedTextView)V).Checked = (false);
        // TODO I believe you should remove your item from SelectedItems
        SelectedItems.Remove(((CheckedTextView)V).Text);
    }
    else
    {
        // set cheek mark drawable and set checked property to true
        // value = "Checked";
        ((CheckedTextView)V).SetCheckMarkDrawable(Resource.Drawable.ic_check);
        ((CheckedTextView)V).Checked = (true);
        addItemIntoCheckedList(((CheckedTextView)V).Text);
    }
}
```

Then on method `GetView`, you should check if your id/text is exist on `SelectedItems` list

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null)
        view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Drawable.filterMultiselectList_view, null);

    _checkedText = view.FindViewById<CheckedTextView>(Resource.Id.chkTV);

    _checkedText.Text = MatchItems[position].displayName;
    _checkedText.SetOnClickListener(this);
    // TODO check if the item is checked based on the id you have saved
    // something like this:
    if (SelectedItems.Contains(_checkedText.Text)) {
        _checkedText.Checked = true;
        _checkedText.SetCheckMarkDrawable(Resource.Drawable.ic_check);
    }
    else {
        _checkedText.Checked = false;
        _checkedText.SetCheckMarkDrawable(0);   
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: After you implemented it, is the result same with before you implemented it?

Comment: Thanks the current issue has been fixed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So how you fixed it? If you could add your own answer, it will be valuable for us who have the same issue.

Comment: Another doubt @HendraWD, how can I set checked items when populating the list?

Comment: What do you mean by "set checked items when populating the list?" Can you show it with example for more clarity?

Comment: I mean, when I open the multiselect list I would like to set few items as checked which will be coming from database.

Comment: ie. Suppose conside that `MatchItems[position].isSelected` gives me the selected values, then how will I be able to set checked checkboxes?

Comment: If that is the case, you don't even need `SelectedItems`. You could directly set `MatchItems[position].isSelected = true/false` from `OnClick`, then update `AllItems` data with the same value. Then from `GetView`, instead of `if (SelectedItems.Contains(_checkedText.Text))`, you could replace with `if (MatchItems[position].isSelected)`. With that, you could have pre-checked items if you already set `MatchItems[position].isSelected` from database.

Comment: Cant get `position` in `OnClick`

Comment: You could set tag to a view and put your position there, so when `OnClick` called, you could get tag from that view, which is the position of the item. You could also directly use Delegates https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/ from `GetView` method, so you could use the position directly from there.

Answer (score 0):

You are managing selected items in separate list `SelectedItems` so when content of `MatchItems` change `SelectedItems` become out date instead of managing it separately define a `boolean` in your model `MatchItems` `isSelected/isChecked` and update it `onclick()`

Comment: How would I have to add isSelected/isChecked?

Comment: I have been stuck at this from last 2 days and my client is dancing on my head for the output. If you can help then It would be really appreciated.