# Remember selected state of RadioButton inside a list

Tags: android, radio-button, listitem, radio-group

I have a `ListView` with several items so that these will be re-used during scrolling.
An item is composed by a couple of `TextViews` and a `RadioGroup`, containing 3 `RadioButtons`.

The issue I'm having is that when I select for example a `RadioButton` for each of the 5 items, when I scroll the list down and back up again, the selection I did in the beginning is not being saved (which means no `RadioButton` or the wrong one will be shown as selected) while it can also happen that some `RadioButtons` will appear as selected even if I never tapped on those.

I'm trying to save the `checkedId` of the selection in a list but without luck.

Following my code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ...
    int questionID = question.getQuestionID();
    if (mappedSelectedAnswer.containsKey(questionID)) {
        radioGroup.check(mappedSelectedAnswer.get(questionID));
    } else {
        radioGroup.check(-1);
    }
    ...
}
```

And the RadioGroupListener

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        if (checkedId != -1) {
            mappedSelectedAnswer.put(questionID, checkedId);
        }
    ...
    });
```

`mappedSelectedAnswer` is a List with key `questionID`, value the `checkedId`

As anyone have any suggestion to this issue?

Thanks

Comment: This is probably due to your `RadioGroup` being recycled as you scroll. [Check out this answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937581/android-how-to-make-radiogroup-work-correctly-in-a-listview)

Comment: As I already specified I already know what's the cause, what I need is an efficient solution. I checked the answer you linked but i don't get the point. Can you be more specific? thanks

Answer (score 0):

you might need to declare all of them into separate RadioGroup to select them for each Item. I hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You need three things

1- A List to store the selected ID of each RadioGroup

2- A listener in the RadioGroup to set/reset the selected id when u tab on it

3- The adapter will check this list when creating the view and select the item that you saved in the listener

Comment: I did that, the problem is that when I scroll and I check the radio button, also the `onCheckedListener` will be called and will set the current value for also another item.

Comment: The listener looks fine. Where do you get the question and the radioGroup from?

Comment: Question comes from `getItem(position)`, Radiogroup comes from `convertView.findViewById`

Answer (score 0):

For Example:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/group"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Standard Taxi (upto 4 passengers)"
        android:id="@+id/standardTaxi"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="radio"
        android:checked="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wagon(upto 4 passengers)"
        android:id="@+id/wagon"
        android:layout_below="@+id/standardTaxi"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

        android:onClick="radio"
        android:checked="false" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Wheelchair Accessible Taxi"
        android:id="@+id/wheelchair"
        android:layout_below="@+id/wagon"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="radio"

        android:checked="false" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Van/Maxi(5-11 passengers)"
        android:id="@+id/van"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:onClick="radio"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:checked="false" />
</RadioGroup>
```